# Why does TFS say that I need to accept the licenses to make an android build?

Tags: android, tfs, tfsbuild

I have Team Foundation Server 2018 Express installed on the same machine as my android studio. My project builds just fine in android studio. But when I try to build it from TFS, I get the error:

```
2018-06-27T18:07:46.5160178Z FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
2018-06-27T18:07:46.5250007Z 
2018-06-27T18:07:46.5319886Z * What went wrong:
2018-06-27T18:07:46.5374784Z A problem occurred configuring project ':androidhelper'.
2018-06-27T18:07:46.5374784Z > Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
2018-06-27T18:07:46.5414710Z      platforms;android-26 Android SDK Platform 26
2018-06-27T18:07:46.5444654Z      build-tools;27.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3
2018-06-27T18:07:46.5449640Z   To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
2018-06-27T18:07:46.5464600Z   Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
2018-06-27T18:07:46.5499548Z   
2018-06-27T18:07:46.5514516Z   Using Android SDK: C:\Users\CAA\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools
```

After checking in the SDK-Manager of android studio, the packages are, as far as I can tell, all installed:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/ZVLbIL7.png]

[image: https://i.imgur.com/epmkNkH.png]

On other threads I've found that using

```
sdkmanager --licenses
```

from command line might solve this issue. But according to the output, everything is accepted:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/EXnHr1H.png]

How do I archive my TFS to build the android project?

**Update:**

Other things I've tried:

1. I've deleted the folders of the platform and build tools. In addition I've deleted the content of the licenses folder. After reinstalling everything with the sdkmanager.bat and calling the --licenses option, everything is as it was before.
2. I've used the sdkmanager UI in android studio to uninstall and install the buildtools and the platform.
3. installed VS community edition, because i've found cases here on stackoverflow, where that was the solution
4. ensured that the agent service is running with the my login data
5. removed the agent service, deleted it entirely and downloaded it fresh.

Comment: Does the build agent run with the same account as you sign in?

Comment: yes. It's running with my login data.

Answer (score 1):

Try below items to narrow down the issue:

- Run below command :

  `cd $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin ./sdkmanager --update`

  `%ANDROID_HOME%/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses`
- Remove and install again:

  1, Remove the platforms\android-26 folder.

  2, Run `sdkmanager "platforms;android-26"` in the android-sdk\bin
  folder.

  3, Press `y` to accept the license and wait until it's installed.

  Do the same thing for `build-tools;27.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3`
- Uninstall and reinstall from SDK-Manager

  1, Uninstall the `SDK Platform 26` and `Build-Tools 27.0.3` and reinstall them again in SDK-Manager

  2, Run `%ANDROID_HOME%/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses` and accept all the licenses.
- Deploy a new agent on a different machine and install the Android SDK
  on it. Try it again.

Comment: Hi. I've tried the first options (update, delete, uninstall), without any change of the situation. Currently no other machine is avaiable :(

Comment: @CAA Just try to deploy a new agent on the same develop machine, then check it again.

Comment: i completly removed the agent and downloaded it new for good measure, but the error is still unchanged :'(

Comment: @CAA Do you have other environments, do they have the same issue?

Comment: sadly I only have this one environment avaiable.